# How do I display different sayings, based on a random number

Tags: android, integer, random, switch-statement

How can I display back to the user a basic popup with a saying based on a random number generated.  I wanted to use a switch statement, but that just displays all the sayings, ie:

```
int random = (int) Math.ceil(Math.random() * 5);

      switch(random){
            case 1:
                showToast(this, "Saying 1.");

            case 2:
                showToast(this, "Saying 2.");
}
```

etc....

Like I said, this displays all 5 case statements, is there a better way to random generate and display based on the number, or am I doing it all wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: I thought of this once. but I gave when I couldnt answer : Whatif there are 1000 sayings. Cant have 1000 swtch cases. An answer here would benefit me also :)

Comment: Dude... u r missing the Break; :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `case` statements inside a switch "fall through" if you don't `break` out of them.

It should be like this:

```
switch(random) {
   case 1:
      statement;
      break;
   case 2:
      statement;
      break;
...
}
```

The break statement jumps to the next line after the switch statement.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try some thing like

```
String[] sayings = {"Saying 1.", "Saying 2.", "Saying 3.", "Saying 4.", "Saying 5."};
int random = (int) Math.ceil(Math.random() * 5);
showToast(this, sayings[random]);
```

and if you have more items then you can prepare the string array dynamically before use.

Answer (score 0):

If there are many sayings... you can also put a .txt file in your assets folder with numerous sayings (one per line), read it and display the saying from a randomly generated line number..

```
Activity.getAssets().open("sayingsfile.txt");
```